# Subsetting JSON and Mustache

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache, zepto

I have a potentially VERY large json object (which I have no control over), I'm attempting to output a list of the json records (in this case it's people) - and I started to use Mustache.js - but the structure of this particular JSON object is causing me fits.

I started down a path of parsing the complex object (many details about each person) into a simpler object (just the people details I actually need) - it appears, I actually accomplished that, but still having Mustache issues and I'm more than a tad concerned about efficiency.

So on to the question - given a JSON object like

```
var data = {"totalrows":3,"autoinc":4,"rows":{    
"1":[{"name":"agent","value":"Bill Summers"},{"name":"firstname","value":"Mike"{"name":"lastname","value":"Goldberg"},{"name":"companyname","value":"Vandelay Industries"},{"name":"department","value":"Import Export"}],
"2":[{"name":"agent","value":"Mark Jacobs"},{"name":"firstname","value":"John"},{"name":"lastname","value":"Stewart"},{"name":"companyname","value":"Vandelay Industries"},{"name":"department","value":"Sales"},],
"3":[{"name":"agent","value":"Heidi Floss"},{"name":"firstname","value":"Stuart"},{"name":"lastname","value":"Manning"},{"name":"companyname","value":"Vandelay Industries"},{"name":"department","value":"Accounts"}]
}
}
```

Here's an example of the approach I was taking - again - need actual results, and some advice as to best practices with this kind of thing

Here's where I stumbled [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sauldraws/8xS8u/)

How would you output a list like

- Mike Goldberg: Import Export, Vandelay Industries
- John Stewart: Sales, Vandelay Industries
- Stuart Manning:  Accounts, Vandelay Industries

TIA

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8xS8u/1/

Comment: Yury Well that certainly works a treat.. done and done..

Answer (score 0):

When handling a large object as this, you might want to **consider paging**. You certainly don't want to go over the whole set of rows.

In other words to get a certain set of rows for display do something like this:

```
var data = yourData; //your JSON

resultsPerPage = 20;
currentPage = 2; // for example (starts from 1)

start = 1 + (currentPage*resultsPerPage) - resultsPerPage;
end = currentPage * resultsPerPage;

resultsToDisplay = [];
for(i=start; i<=end; i++){
    resultsToDisplay.push(data.rows[i]);
}
```

This may not be a full answer, but it may be useful to you, as pagination when displaying results from a large object is a must.

After that you can output the data from the acquired set, for example by appending them to a DIV.

```
resultsToDisplay.each(function(result){
    output = result.get('firstname') + " " + result.get('lastname') + ": " + result.get('department') + ", " + result.get('companyname') + "<br/>"; 
    $('#yourOutputDiv').html().append(output);
});
```

Comment: Thanks - Definitely something I'll consider - although doesn't solve my template issue

Comment: @sauldraws is this edit more helpful to you? I'm trying, but your question is kind of broad ;)

Comment: If you refer to the jsFiddle in my original post - I'm specifically trying to utilize mustache templates - I didn't intend for the question to be broad

Comment: @sauldraws oh sorry then, I must have overlooked that. If you want I will remove my post.